# How to repeat and print 2 or more for loops?

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to print out values from my txt file. I created a struct so that I can easily search for the element in the txt file. So for my first for loop I searched for "CC" as the first option and then I print. It works. However when I try copy the same loop and search for something else, lets say "SN" so that I can print all the values with SN as the first option, the second and subsequent loop does not print. It only works if I copy the long code again and create a new function but I do not want to do that because I try to keep it compact.

```
cout << "\nCC Students:" << endl;
int cc = 0;
for (; it != v.end(); it++)
{
    if ((*it).First == "CC"){
        cout << (*it).Name << " " << (*it).GPA << "\n";
        if (++cc == 10)
            break;
    }
} // can print


cout << "\nSN Students:" << endl;
int sn = 0;
for (; it != v.end(); it++)
{
    if ((*it).First == "SN"){
        cout << (*it).Name << " " << (*it).GPA << "\n";
        if (++sn == 10)
            break;
    }
} // cannot print
```

Comment: You should be setting `it` to `v.begin()` in each for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't show the initialization of `it`, but from the context it seems to be an iterator on `v`. The first loop exhausts the iterator, and terminates when `it` reaches `v.end()`. When you start another loop, you should reinitialize `it` to `v.begin()`, e.g.:

```cpp
for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
// Here ^
```

Comment: Yup. the it is from an iterator. Anyways, it works. Thanks! I didn't know that the loop doesn't continue from the start and I needed to include the v.begin().